# filter() function returning columns without desired rows with R

Tags: r, filter, tidyverse

Good evening, I'm trying to subset the columns and rows showing the countries with the lowest and highest life expectancies in 1960 with the filter function. When I run the code I get a data frame with the desired columns but 0 rows. The filter function worked when I subsetted the columns and rows with the lowest and highest fertility rates in 1960.
The dataset is a CSV file containing everything except the columns for life expectancies. The columns were two separate vectors meant to be added to the dataset.

code

```
 # Lowest and highest life expectancies in 1960
 data_1960 %>%
 filter(Life.Exp.1960 %in% c(28.21161, 73.54976)) %>%
 select(1, 3, 6)

 # lowest and highest fertility rates in 1960
 data_1960 %>%
 filter(Fertility.Rate %in% c(1.94, 8.187)) %>%
 select(1, 3, 5)
```

output

```
                           A data.frame: 0 × 3
                 Country.Name   Region  Life.Exp.1960
                          <chr> <chr>   <dbl>

                           A data.frame: 2 × 3
                 Country.Name   Region  Fertility.Rate
                          <chr> <chr>   <dbl>
                         Latvia Europe  1.940
                         Rwanda Africa  8.187
```

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. You should not use `%in% with floating point numbers. Testing for exactly equality for decimals doesn't work the same for humans and computers.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a precision issue; try using `near()`

```
data_1960 %>%
 filter(near(Life.Exp.1960, 28.21161) | near(Life.Exp.1960, 73.54976)) %>%
 select(1, 3, 6)
```

Comment: I tried that and received the same output.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. It's weird but when I use the summarise function to find the lowest and highest values in the dataset R doesn't output the full value (some numbers on the right side of the decimal are omitted).